# Control Panel Icon left after MSI Uninstallation

Tags: deployment, windows-installer

I built a MSI for unattended deployment which installes a application (usually installed with install shield which is not supported by the customers deployment software).

This MSI also installes a icon in the Control Panel.

After uninstallation everything is removed but the icon in the Control Panel.

The funny thing is: I neighter can't find a .cpl nor a registry key regarding to this icon.

Where I searched for the registry keys:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \
  Explorer \ ControlPanel \ NameSpace
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion
  \ Explorer \ ControlPanel \ NameSpace

Comment: If it's 32-bit on a 64-bit system, are you also looking in the `Wow6432Node` branch?

Comment: Yes i searched there too...